# How to find orthonormal basis of a plane in $P_3 (R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

In the question, we want to find the matrix for orthogonal projection on W.
We have W = span{1, x} and we need $P_w (x + x^2) $
The inner product is:
 $<p(x), q(x)> = \int_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x) dx$

I understand that first, we need to find the orthonormal basis for W. I know how to do that for vector spaces in $R^n $ but I can't understand how to use that here. I also know how to find the inner product of two functions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, **what inner product** are you using here? Without this the question can't even be understood.

Comment: I have made an edit to the question. Sorry for not mentioning before

Comment: Note that $1$ and $x$ are orthogonal.

Comment: I just realised that too. Some scaling is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *exactly* the same as you'd do in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ with Gram-Schmidt:

$$u_1=\frac1{\left\|1\right\|}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\langle1,1\rangle=\int_{-1}^1dx=2\implies u_1=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

and now

$$w:=x-\langle x,u_1\rangle u_1=x-\frac12\int_{-1}^1x\,dx=x$$

(and this means $\;1\perp x\;$) , so finally

$$u_2=\frac x{\left\|x\right\|}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\langle x,x\rangle=\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\frac23\implies u_2=\sqrt\frac32\,x$$

and there you have your orthonormal basis for $\;V\;$

Comment: Okay, so when we find $P_w (x + x^2)$, do we use the same method as in $R^n$ for that as well?
As in, we need $<x + x^2, u_1>u_1 + <x + x^2, u_2>u_2$ ?

Comment: @user319373 Assuming $\;P_W\;$ means the orthogonal projection, yes.